# Angular JS Email Validation with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sign up form for an application, and angular js is responsible for its validation.

I ran into an issue when Angular js wasn't accepting an email address which has apostrophe in it. **"Pear'lpeerh.shin@xyz.com"** .

I found out that angularJs doesnt like unicode characters in email address.

Has anyone else came across an issue like this, I am interested in knowing my options to get away with this bug in angularJs.

Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom validation function? http://jsfiddle.net/adamdbradley/Qdk5M/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If having html5 `<input type=email />` is not critical, you can use `<input type=text  />` and pattern validation

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="field" ng-pattern="EMAIL_REGEXP" />
```

and you can use regex that @Andy Joslin posted in his answer

```
 $scope.EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i;
```

Comment: The REGEX that you provided didn't address the apostrophe issue. I added "  '  " in the REGEX in the angular.js file, and it worked. I didn't change the input type to "text" either.

Comment: I checked your answer, as it may help someone with issues like these with the use of ng-pattern.

Comment: When using this expression directly in the ng-pattern without a variable, the `\.` must be escaped twice as it is an expression WITHIN a string. `\\.`

Comment: FYI <input type=email /> is important if you are writing a mobile application to display a suitable keyboard for email entry

Comment: tried this regex, didn't work for 'üñîçøðé@example.com

Answer (score 11):

AngularJS uses this regular expression to test email: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L4

What you could do is write a directive that checks it yourself.  Just copy the one from AngularJS and use your own regexp: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L606-L614

```
myApp.directive('nanuEmail', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, model) {
      //change this:
      var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
      var emailValidator = function(value) {
      if (!value || EMAIL_REGEXP.test(value)) {
        model.$setValidity('email', true);
        return value;
      } else {
        model.$setValidity('email', false);
        return undefined;
      }
      model.$parsers.push(emailValidator);
      model.$formatters.push(emailValidator);
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can just do:

```
<input nanu-email ng-model="userEmail">
```

Comment: Alternatively he can just use `<input type="text" ng-model="field" ng-pattern="MYUNIEMALREGEX" />`

Answer (score 1):

I just updated the regex in the angular.js file (added " **'** " in the expression) and it worked, without making any other changes.

EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-**'**]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/ . Thanks Vittore, for giving me the idea to update REGEX. :)

Answer (score 0):

why do you return undefined?

Refactoring of the function:

```
var verificationEmail = function (viewValue) {
  if ((typeof viewValue != "undefined") && viewValue != "") {
    return regex.test(viewValue);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular do not support the apostrophe(`'`) in email Id. If you need to validate the apostrophe in Angular, you need to change the regular expression from:

```
(/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/)
```

To:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+'-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/.
```

It will work perfectly.